# Handling COM serial port communication

Tags: serial-port, interrupt-handling

I was thinking about a best approach to properly handle the serial port communication in my program. I have some device that sends me data, im reciving it using DataRecieved event and ReadExisting method in it. Everything that it reads is being put inside a buffer, when last line equals some string then i start to parse it into some kind of packet.

Aside from that, when i send data to this device and wait for response, i mark flag

```
bool isReady = false;

while(!isReady)
    Thread.Sleep(500);
```

And in data parsing method i set this flag to true so when I recieve packet data, code can jump out of this loop and continue to work as needed. But in my opinion this is not a clean/good way to do this. And there is a problem sometimes, if device will not send the packet I need, so program is being stuck in the loop forever.

I was wondering, how would you guys resolve this case in your code?

Thanks, and sorry for bad english.

Comment: Sounds like you are using the DataReceived event.  Don't use it, you have no use for it.  Just call Read() directly.

Answer (score 0):

Don't just wait for a response in an endless loop. Use the events like you previously mentioned to get the data. See this other SO question also. [SerialPort class and DataReceived event... Getting bytes. Use ReadLine or ReadExisting? Any examples?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4232355/serialport-class-and-datareceived-event-getting-bytes-use-readline-or-readex)

Comment: Waiting for event would be cool way to handle issues called by device itself. But how to do this when I'm sending one request to the device, then i need to wait for response, and depend on that response send other request etc? I can't just exit from method and wait for an event.

Comment: By using events you can maintain a responsive application whilst still communicating with the serial port. Just maintain the state (what the last action/request was in this instance ) in the parent or a class encapsulating the logic. Think event driven rather than just a single method. This way you have the ability to cancel out etc as you could build that logic in

Comment: Hmm, can you post some pseudocode or maybe some articles to show me examples of how would it looks like? I have no idea how this can be done event driven and still maintain proper order of commands handling.

Answer (score -1):

For now i've added a 5sec timeout using following code:

```
bool isReady = false;
DateTime timeout = DateTime.Now;
while(!isReady)
{
    Thread.Sleep(500);
    if((DateTime.Now-timeout).TotalMiliseconds >= 5000)
        break;
}
```

So when no response is recieved then it just jumps out of this loop. This is solving one of my problems, but still I would like to know other ways to handle this. If you guys have any ideas, please share them.