# Serial port doesn't read all data

Tags: c#, serial-port

I am reading from a serial port Rs232. I am facing a very strange problem. 
The total bytes from incoming information is 37 bytes. In my computer, each time which i have interrupt in my serial port, the information is exactly 37bytes.

example abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890! and so on till 3

but in another pc, my imformation is been seperated to 8 bytes

example  abcdefgh, in next interrup ijklmnop , in next interrup qrstuvwx and so on

Here is my serial port code:

```
public static string Rs232Weight = "0";//Αυτό είναι για να παίρνει την τιμή η ζυγαριά
    public static readonly object lockWeight = new object();
    private static SerialPort mySerialPort;
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            mySerialPort = new SerialPort(textBox1.Text);
            mySerialPort.BaudRate = 9600;
            mySerialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
            mySerialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            mySerialPort.DataBits = 8;
            mySerialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
            mySerialPort.Open();
            mySerialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);

        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }
    private static void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
            lock (lockWeight)
            {
                string tmp = sp.ReadExisting();
                ExportFile(Convert.ToString(tmp) + "|" + Convert.ToString(tmp.Length));

            }

        }
        catch //(Exception ex)
        {
            // Dialogs.SingleMessage(Convert.ToString(ex), "Προειδοποίηση");

        }
    }
```

Comment: The data received event can happen at any time after data is received - there is no guarantee that the event will happen after the first or the 37th character or any where in between - so if you are using that event, you need to ensure that you can concatenate data until you are sure it is complete.

Comment: Finally i replaced ReadExisting with ReadLine and problem solved. I don't know difference between of two but it seems to work

Comment: [ReadLine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.readline?view=netframework-4.8) reads the stream until the next `NewLine` value. [ReadExisting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.readexisting?view=netframework-4.8) reads all immediately available bytes in the stream and input buffer.

Comment: There is no guarantee that serial data will be received in one chunk.  In windows there are timers that move the data from the UART in the PC to the application.   One different PCs the timing will be different especially if the machines have different services installed and running other application in parallel.  You must parse the data to the last character of each message (usually the return) before processing the data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SerialPort class and DataReceived event... Getting bytes. Use ReadLine or ReadExisting? Any examples?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4232355/serialport-class-and-datareceived-event-getting-bytes-use-readline-or-readex)